# Express.js require session to access particular routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app where certain pages require that the user be logged in.

I am not sure if there is something built in for this, but what I have for doing this is as follows:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.session.username) {
    app.get('/project/create', projectCtrl.create)
    app.get('/project/create/save', projectCtrl.save)
  } else {
    return res.redirect('/')
  }
  next()
})
```

Is this the correct way of doing this, or is there a better way in express? The way I am doing it kind of feels a little hacky.

Comment: This is not going to come close to working.  Might work for your very first request to the server would not work after that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's one correct way of doing it. What you have is an ***application-level middleware*** in `express`. It gets called for every request the application receives.

You can extract the `username` check and apply that as a ***route middleware substack***. This way the middleware only gets executed for the routes it's applied to.

```
function gatePass(req, res, next) {
   if(req.session.username) {
      next();
   }
   else {
     return res.redirect('/');
   }
}

app.get('/project/create', gatePass, projectCtrl.create)
app.get('/project/create/save', gatePass, projectCtrl.save)
```

You can take this a bit further if you'll like to separate concerns by using *express router* together with ***route-level middleware***. This also applies a middleware directly to the routes.

```
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/project/create', gatePass);
router.use('/project/create/save', gatePass);

router.get('/project/create', projectCtrl.create);
router.get('/project/create/save', projectCtrl.save);

app.use('/', router);
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution work. It's not the best but for small project it will be good. The only drawback is that you will need to define every route you want to be check with a session.

Nodejs is the world of middleware, so why not use one? I think it's the best thing to do.

Verify is a file where I export my middleware and I apply it on all my router.. (in this case it's just to check if the user is logged or not)

```
var verify = require('./verify');

router.all('/*', verify.isLogged, function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.decoded._doc.isLogged == "") {
    next();
  }
  else {
    res.json("error");
  }
});
```

This way, if in the future you need to check one thing, then another one, you will just need to call you function where you want to check

```
router.get('/test', verify.isLogged, verify.isAdmin function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.decoded._doc.isAdmin == "") {
    next();
  }
  else {
    res.json("error");
  }
});
```